# what is the maximum duration of moderator ? How many years they will remain in their positions as moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderators, soft-question

I think MSE is like a democratic country. we cast vote and choosing our favourite USER

My question :

what  is the maximum duration of moderator ? How many years they will remain in their positions as moderator ?

Just like president or prime minister has limited terms on his office.For example Trump and Obama

Comment: I think the limit is 100 years.

Comment: okay@AsafKaragila that means unlimited term

Comment: Not really, @jasmine. At least they cannot give it to the grandkids. (Just kidding, there is no limit at all)

Comment: @jasmine, I understand.  But please know you can ask many such questions in the mods' office chat, or CURED, even Mathematics chatrooms.  I'll delete my former comment.

Comment: A related post on [meta.se]: [Should Community Moderators be "elected for life", or have terms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/984)

Comment: Moderators are elected every year, so, normally, the limit is one year. (There are famous exceptions though.) After new elections, old moderators may or may not continue, depending on the outcome, just as in politics.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Elections are supposed to be held "at regular intervals", but it's not guaranteed that an election will take place every year (as can be seen from the [list of past elections](https://math.stackexchange.com/election)). It's probably based on the workload of the current moderator team and whether they feel more hands are required on deck.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm also quite sure that your interpretation of the limit being one year is incorrect. I believe any current moderator can step down whenever they wish to, not just at the end of an election. And, I don't think the outcome of an election really matters in that regard, since elections are always held to *add* moderators to the team, not to replace any moderators. (An election could be held to replace a seat previously vacated by a moderator, but that's a different scenario.)

Comment: Is there any proviso for recall elections? or impeachment?

Comment: @GerryMyerson No; see [What processes exist to issue formal warnings or remove moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336173/986753) on [meta.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered in the [Help Center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/) article titled [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators).

> At Stack Exchange, we believe moderation starts with the community itself, so in addition to all users gaining [privileges](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) through reputation earned, each site has moderators elected through popular vote. We hold regular elections to determine who these community moderators will be …. Moderators are elected for life, though they may resign (or, in very rare cases, be removed).

Details about the kinds of scenarios under which a moderator's diamond can be removed can be found in the FAQ on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) titled [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/986753). From the section "How long does a moderator's term last?":

> [T]here are a few cases where a user's moderator diamond may be removed:
>
> - First, moderators may resign from their post at any time.
> - Second, inactive moderators who haven't performed a single moderator action for the past six months will be contacted and asked if they wish to continue being a moderator. If there is no response or if they respond "no", their privileges [will be removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338006/986753).
> - Third, there are [procedures for removing moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336173/986753) in case the moderator's actions are causing issues with the community or among the moderator team, if the moderator violates the [moderator agreement](https://math.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement), or if rights need to be *immediately* revoked in an emergency.

You can also find some discussion about why the moderation system is set up like this in the post [Should Community Moderators be "elected for life", or have terms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/984/986753) over on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), as well as its [linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/984).